# Python: How can I check whether a object is a module?

Tags: python, object, module

How can I check in Python whether a given object is a module or not?

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["sys"].__class__
<class 'module'>
>>> isinstance(sys.modules["sys"], module)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module' is not defined
>>> sys.modules["sys"].__class__.__module__
'builtins'
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module'
```

Comment: I hate to be that guy but why do you need to know this?  If you're asking yourself "is this arbitrary object a module?", it throws up some red flags for me saying you might be too far down the wrong path.

Comment: I just was wondering myself, I do not want to use it in any project. First I thought of using `isinstance` but there not seems to be a module's class.

Comment: It never hurts to understand how things work - just don't use it for evil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import sys, types
>>> isinstance(sys, types.ModuleType)
True
```

the `types` module also provides many other types:

```
>>> dir(types)
['BooleanType', 'BufferType', 'BuiltinFunctionType', 'BuiltinMethodType', 'ClassType', 'CodeType', 'ComplexType', 'DictProxyType', 'DictType', 'DictionaryType', 'EllipsisType', 'FileType', 'FloatType', 'FrameType', 'FunctionType', 'GeneratorType', 'GetSetDescriptorType', 'InstanceType', 'IntType', 'LambdaType', 'ListType', 'LongType', 'MemberDescriptorType', 'MethodType', 'ModuleType', 'NoneType', 'NotImplementedType', 'ObjectType', 'SliceType', 'StringType', 'StringTypes', 'TracebackType', 'TupleType', 'TypeType', 'UnboundMethodType', 'UnicodeType', 'XRangeType', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

inspect.ismodule is pretty much the simplest you can get.

```
import inspect
inspect.ismodule(inspect)
```

Comment: +1: The code for which simply does `return isinstance(object, types.ModuleType)`..

Answer (score -2):

`if type(obj) == type(__builtin__)` should help

Comment: No. First of all, `isinstance` is the correct way to check types (if it proves necessary); second of all, not all modules are builtins.

Comment: thanks. SO ate the double underscores on both sides of 'builtin'

Comment: @darkphoenix: wrap your code with a left apostrophe.  But `__builtin__` doesn't exist, does it?  [By which I mean isn't it `__builtins__`, with an s?]

Comment: (1) Learn how to format your answers; (2) My criticism does not relate to your typography.